# What is the range of random values given by Object Info node?

Tags: node-editor

When using the Object Info node and the random option is chosen, what is the range of values this output can take? For example, does it generate random values between [0, 1], etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, *Random* output of *Object Info Node* generates numbers in the $0$-$1$ range, as stated in this [Blender Artists thread](https://blenderartists.org/t/cycles-object-info-node-how-to/546274).

If you need different values you can use the *Math Nodes* to convert it into the desired range.

You can also get random colors by running the output through a *Color Ramp* node

Comment: Thanks! This should definitely be in the docs.